# Cannot Get SQLite To Load In Navigation Drawer Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, navigation-drawer

So I am nearing the end of my course on Android Studio and unfortunately ran into issues with connecting a DB to an app. Basically, by using a navigation drawer layout, I'm to display a simple fragment allowing a user to input data. That data should be inserted into the DB on one page and on another I am to be able to view the submitted data via the DB. My frankencode is listed below and I call it that because I altered source code provided from the professor along with other tidbits I've seen from other sources. We were provided code for the database helper, insert page, and display page but the Main activity isn't offered so I'm unsure why I'm getting errors when I try to input the information. Any help is appreciated.

```
switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_program1:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.firstPage, new 
            Prog1()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_program2:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.secPage, new P 
            Prog2()).commit();
            break;
    }
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
databasehelper mydb;
DrawerLayout drawer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mydb = new databasehelper(this);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem)
{
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_program1:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.firstPage, new Prog1()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_program2:
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.secPage, new Prog2()).commit();
            break;
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

DBHelper

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class databasehelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public static final String database_name="Ponduce Farms Reservations";
public static final String table_name="names";
public static final String col1="id";
public static final String col2="FIRSTNAME";
public static final String col3="LASTNAME";
public static final String col4="EMAIL";
public static final String col5="PHONE";
public static final String col6="DATE";

public databasehelper(Context context) {
    super(context, database_name, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL("create table " + table_name +"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FIRSTNAME TEXT, LASTNAME TEXT, EMAIL TEXT, PHONE TEXT, DATE TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +table_name);
}

public boolean insertData(String fname,String lname,String email, String phone, String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(col2,fname);
    contentValues.put(col3,lname);
    contentValues.put(col4,email);
    contentValues.put(col5,phone);
    contentValues.put(col6,date);
    long result = db.insert(database_name,null ,contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public List<String> showallrecords()
{
    List<String> recordlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor records = database.rawQuery("select * from names", null);

    if (records.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            recordlist.add(records.getString(2)+ " "+ "FirstName: "+
                           records.getString(3)+" "+"LastName: "+
                           records.getString(4)+" "+"Email: "+
                           records.getString(5 )+" "+"Phone: "+
                           records.getString(6)+" "+"Date: "+
                    "\n");
        }
        while (records.moveToNext());
    }
    return recordlist;
}
```

}

Insert (Content Main)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class Prog1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
View myview;
databasehelper mydatabasehelper;
EditText fname,lname,email,phonenum;
Button submitbut;
Spinner dates;
String resDate;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main,container,false);
    mydatabasehelper = new databasehelper(getActivity());
    fname=(EditText)myview.findViewById(R.id.first_input);
    lname=(EditText)myview.findViewById(R.id.last_input);
    email=(EditText)myview.findViewById(R.id.email_input);
    phonenum=(EditText)myview.findViewById(R.id.phone_input);
    submitbut=(Button)myview.findViewById(R.id.button);
    dates = (Spinner)myview.findViewById(R.id.dates);
    String resDate = dates.getSelectedItem().toString();
    submitbut.setOnClickListener(this);
    return myview;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    boolean isIn = mydatabasehelper.insertData(fname.getText().toString(),lname.getText().toString(),email.getText().toString(),phonenum.getText().toString(),resDate);

    if(isIn==true)
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Data Not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Display:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Prog2 extends Fragment {
View myview;
databasehelper mydatabasehelper;
ListView recordlistview;
ArrayList<String> arraylist;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    myview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.program2,container,false);


    mydatabasehelper=new databasehelper(getActivity());

    recordlistview=(ListView)myview.findViewById(R.id.dbinfo);

    List<String> records = mydatabasehelper.showallrecords();

    adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,records);

    recordlistview.setAdapter(adapter);

    return myview;
}
```

}

---

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0900ac (com.example.chp5:id/secPage) for fragment Prog2{7e8490c #0 id=0x7f0900ac}
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1454)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

This is the error I get.

Comment: `so I'm unsure why I'm getting errors when I try to input the information.` what errors?

Answer (score 0):

You have `long result = db.insert(database_name,null ,contentValues);`

This is trying to insert a row into a **table** which doesn't exist as you supplied the database name instead of the **table** name.

Change to `long result = db.insert(table_name,null ,contentValues);`